long to wide transformation without creating lists and nulls
this is a followup question from my previous post.
My dataframe arranges visit for a specific PK based on dates, with a columns for:

visit number
visit date
exam done in that visit

I am trying to turn it back to a wide dataframe. in which, each row is a visit, and there is a column for each test type. for each visit, columns that
Netting this dataframe:
# A tibble: 14 × 9
# Groups:   PK, visit [7]
   PK        visit test         date       toddler module1   rbs   srs adi_score
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>        <date>       <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 683865865     1 date_toddler 2020-12-08       7      NA    NA    NA        NA
 2 683865865     2 date_toddler 2021-11-10      10      NA    NA    NA        NA
 3 683865865     3 date_module1 2022-02-10      NA      10    NA    NA        NA
 4 683865865     4 date_module1 2022-08-24      NA      10    NA    NA        NA
 5 683865865     4 date_srs_pr  2022-08-24      NA      NA    NA    79        NA
 6 683865865     5 date_srs_pr  2023-01-12      NA      NA    NA    83        NA
 7 683865865     6 date_module1 2023-08-21      NA      10    NA    NA        NA
 8 683865865     6 date_srs_pr  2023-09-21      NA      NA    NA    90        NA
 9 683865865    NA date_adi     NA              NA      NA    NA    NA        NA
10 683865865    NA date_module2 NA              NA      NA    NA    NA        NA
11 683865865    NA date_module3 NA              NA      NA    NA    NA        NA
12 683865865    NA date_module4 NA              NA      NA    NA    NA        NA
13 683865865    NA date_rbsr    NA              NA      NA    NA    NA        NA
14 683865865    NA date_srs_sch NA              NA      NA    NA    NA        NA

example of wanted data:
         PK visit  toddler   module1   rbs   srs  adi_score
1 683865865     1        7        NA    NA    NA         NA
2 683865865     2       10        NA    NA    NA         NA  
3 683865865     3       NA        10    NA    NA         NA
4 683865865     4       NA        10    NA    79         NA
5 683865865     5       NA        NA    NA    83         NA
6 683865865     6       NA        10    NA    90         NA

I have tried melting into long, and then wide again, but because there are multiple ID's each with a different amount of visits, im getting the values in LISTS and NULLS.
"Warning message:
Values from `adi_score`, `ados_module1`, `ados_module2`, `ados_module3`, `ados_module4`, `ados_toddler`,
`rbsr_score`, `srs_preschool` and `srs_school` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
• Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
• Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates.
• Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates."


This doesn‘t necessarily look like a pivot_wider task. Instead, it looks more like you want to filter down to one row per visit, but it is not clear how you‘d decide which rows to keep in case there are duplicate visits, e.g. visit 6 appears two times. What is your rule to define which case you‘d want to keep?

They are both kept. The ideal is to merge the data from these columns. So that visit 6 will include both. This is the same for visit 4.

Need the data. See [MRE]. And if both rows containing visits 4 and 6 are to be "kept", then why are only 1 of each in the "wanted data"?

In tidyverse you can use the following:
library(tidyverse)
df%>%
  filter(!if_all(date:adi_score, is.na)) %>% 
  summarise(across(toddler:adi_score, ~na.omit(.x)[1]), .by=c(PK, visit))

         PK visit toddler module1 rbs srs adi_score
1 683865865     1       7      NA  NA  NA        NA
2 683865865     2      10      NA  NA  NA        NA
3 683865865     3      NA      10  NA  NA        NA
4 683865865     4      NA      10  NA  79        NA
5 683865865     5      NA      NA  NA  83        NA
6 683865865     6      NA      10  NA  90        NA

